# Building a linq expression with only field names

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, lambda

i have three classes like the following

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{  
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddUser")]
    public int? AddUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User AddUser { get; set; }

}

public class Jobs
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddUser")]
    public int? AddUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User AddUser { get; set; }

}
```

and I want to build  queries to select some entities.

but I am going to build the query by reading some values from `db`.
for example i have following strings

```
1-   "Product",
     "Name = "abc"

2-   "Jobs",
     "Name" = "abc"

3-    "Product",
      "AddUser.Name" = "abc"

4-    "Jobs",
      "AddUser.Name" = "abc" || "Name" = "abc"
```

now I need a function to build the proper queries.

my application language is c# and I am using asp.net.
I need queries for entity framework.
what should iI do.

Comment: Any query you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to do it:

1) Hard-code every possible table and column name, like this:

```
if (tableName == "Jobs") query = query.Where(...)
```

This is good solution if you really really sure there will be no future changes in the data models, and the number of tables and columns is small. Otherwise, it is a very bad solution.

2) Use http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library
With this library you can create expression trees from the strings. Don't forget about security issues, because it is not good idea to get a user power to create their own SQL queries.

3) Build your own expression trees. Here is a good article to start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx 
It is a most complicated solution and it allows you control everything you want. It is good solution if there is a limited number of operations you want provide.

4) Build SQL from the string using StringBuilder class, and then, execute SQL. Here is an article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx 
Of course, you should be very careful with this SQL building, because of the security issues. If you plan to work with the queries and modify them (i.e. add additional filters, joins, skip/take, etc) then it is a bad idea.